# Regex to match spaces that are NOT at the beginning of a line?

Tags: regular-expression

I want to remove repeated spaces, but not if they occur at the start of a line (indendation).

Before:

```
line 1
  hi  there      i      have    spaces
```

After:

```
line 1
  hi there i have spaces
```

I've gotten as far as `s/^\s\+/ /g`, but that deletes only duplicate spaces that *are* at the start of the line. I need to know how to negate the `^`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to match the start of the line. Instead, match any non-whitespace character. This should work:

```
s/\S\zs\s\{2,}/ /g
```

Explanation:

- `\S\zs` match any non-whitespace character and set start of pattern match after the character
- `\s\{2,}` match at two or more spaces

Answer (score 3):

[@KarlYngveLervåg's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7915/343) is probably simpler, but you can also achieve this using your original idea of negating the `^` atom. To do so you can use **negative look behind**. (See `:help /\@<!`) which causes an atom to match only when it *doesn't* follow another specified atom, in this case the `^` start of line.

The naive expression below where we simply add this in to your existing expression *doesn't* work, however, because, if your line starts with multiple spaces, the *second* space on the line, and all those that following it, do not immediately follow the start of the line, and thus match:

```
:s/^\@<!\s\+/ g
```

So to fix this, we also need to include these start-of-line spaces as part of the thing we don't want our spaces to follow:

```
:s/\(^\s*\)\@<!\s\+/ /g
```

As @KarlYngveLervåg also noted, we can make this cleaner by only matching when there actually are multiple spaces:

```
:s/\(^\s*\)\@<!\s\{2,}/ /g
```

As a final touch, we can simplify this by using the very magic `\v` atom (`:help /\v`), so we don't have to do quite so much \escaping.

So:

```
    ┌──────────────── 1.     \v - Using "very magic",
    │              ┌─ 2.  s{2,} - Match two or more spaces,
   ┌┤         ┌────┤
   ││         │    │
:s/\v(^\s*)@<!\s{2,}/ /g
     │    ││ │
     └────┤└─┤
          │  └─────── 3.    @<! - That do not follow,
          └────────── 4. (^\s*) - The start of the line followed by
                                  any number of spaces.
```